# Can a c++ template pattern replace an ever growing union?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a simple class that allows an interrupt (or other routine) to schedule a function to be run in the next pass of the main loop code. This works by using a `union` to describe different possible argument patterns.

As is, to add a new type of argument pattern requires

1. Adding a `typedef` for the pattern.
2. Adding a `struct` to the union to represent the arguments.
3. Adding an `addDooer` declaration and function to handle the add.
4. Updating the `loop` code switch statement to handle the new pattern type.

A smidgen of work for every new argument pattern. I am just learning about templates and am wondering if this class can be rewritten to use templates to simplify adding additional argument patterns? And if so, can the patterns also be expanded to allow a different number of arguments as well?

```
typedef void (*looper_runner1)(uint32_t arg1, uint16_t arg2);
typedef void (*looper_runner2)(uint8_t *arg1, uint16_t arg2);

struct LoopDooer
{
    uint16_t type;
    union {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t arg1;
            uint16_t arg2;
            looper_runner1 fn;
        } type1;
        struct
        {
            uint8_t *arg1;
            uint16_t arg2;
            looper_runner2 fn;
        } type2;
    } dooer;
};

class Looper
{

public:

    Looper();
    bool addDooer(looper_runner1 fn, uint32_t arg1, uint16_t arg2);
    bool addDooer(looper_runner2 fn, uint8_t *arg1, uint16_t arg2);
    void loop();

private:
    /* ... actual methods not relevant to question */
};

bool Looper::addDooer(looper_runner1 fn, uint32_t arg1, uint16_t arg2)
{
    LoopDooer *p = new LoopDooer();
    p->type = 1;
    p->dooer.type1.fn = fn;
    p->dooer.type1.arg1 = arg1;
    p->dooer.type1.arg2 = arg2;
    return _add(p);
}

bool Looper::addDooer(looper_runner2 fn, uint8_t *arg1, uint16_t arg2)
{
    LoopDooer *p = new LoopDooer();
    p->type = 2;
    p->dooer.type2.fn = fn;
    p->dooer.type2.arg1 = arg1;
    p->dooer.type2.arg2 = arg2;
    return _add(p);
}

// To be called from main loop
void Looper::loop()
{
    LoopDooer *p;

    /* some code removed that just gets next LoopDooer into pointer p */

    // Do it
    switch (p->type)
    {
    case 1:
        p->dooer.type1.fn(p->dooer.type1.arg1, p->dooer.type1.arg2);
        break;
    case 2:
        p->dooer.type2.fn(p->dooer.type2.arg1, p->dooer.type2.arg2);
        break;
    }
    // Delete it
    delete p;
}
```

Comment: I don't know that templates are the correct approach. They're for uses where the operations are all the same, but the data type varies. You should consider looking at std::bind, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind/

Comment: Adding new types often without adding operations is a classic use case for inheritance-based polymorphism. I'd start there for inspiration. There are ways to make it perhaps less verbose than adding a whole new derived class, but they still come out to the same idea.

Answer (score 3):

All of what you are trying to do here can be done with `std::function` and lambdas directly. They implement all the logic that you want, for arbitrary argument types.

```
#include<functional>

using LoopDooer = std::function<void()>;

template<typename F, typename... Args>
bool Looper::addDooer(F f, Args&&... args) {
    return _add([=]{ f(args...); });
}

void Looper::loop() {
    LoopDooer dooer = /* extract LoopDoer from container */;
    dooer();
}
```

Also note that manual memory management with `new`/`delete` is a bad idea. At the very least use `std::unqiue_ptr`, but you shouldn't really need any dynamic allocation at all. Whatever container you use should probably contain the `LoopDooer`s directly.

Comment: Great, thanks! I suspected there would be something much easier. I learned and wrote a lot of c++ before lambdas and when it barely had templates. Since then (25+ years?) I have been writing in other much higher level languages. Now I have to go back to c++ to write some code for Arduino's but with the old way I used to write it stuck in my head. Good to have a pointer where to start studying!

Comment: @d'ArtagnanEvergreenBarbosa Yes, the newer C++ features make it much easier to write higher level abstractions. Also note that `std::function` doesn't *really* implement your approach. It uses type erasure instead. The union approach you are using is however also implemented in the standard library as `std::variant` since C++17, so there really isn't any reason anymore to write such unions manually. Lambda's are for the most part only syntactical sugar. You could write a templated functor instead. (But that will take a whole class definition, while the lambda can be written in the expression.)